# i have problem with adapter positioning for each item in my project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

this is my recycler view
i create some product and use a recyclerview to show them ... for each product i put button to when ever user select the product shows a field that could add the more amount of product .
but when i click on each button to increase the amount of the product and after that click on other product the amount not start from 1

```
enter code here
```

class RecyclerAdapterMain(

```
val product: ArrayList<ModelProductMain>
```

) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterMain.ViewHolder>() {

```
var num = 1

class ViewHolder(itemview: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemview) {


    val title: TextView = itemview.product_txt
    val price: TextView = itemview.price_product
    val imageproduct: ImageView = itemview.product_image
    val rl_select_item = itemview.rl_section_additive_items
    val add: Button = itemview.btn_icon_add
    val amount: TextView = itemview.amount_value
    val btn_add_item: Button = itemview.button_add_product


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {


    val layoutview =
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.product_items, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(layoutview)

}

override fun getItemCount() = product.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {


    val products = product[position]
    holder.title.text = products.title
    holder.price.text = products.price.toString()
    Picasso.get().load(products.image).into(holder.imageproduct)



    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

        val bundle = Bundle()
        val myfragment = ItemDetailsfragment()
        myfragment.arguments = bundle


        val activity = it.context as AppCompatActivity
        activity.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.homepage, myfragment)
            .commit()


        bundle.putString("title", products.title)
        bundle.putString("price", products.price.toString())
        bundle.putString("image", products.image.toString())


    }

    holder.rl_select_item.visibility = View.GONE

    holder.add.setOnClickListener {

        holder.rl_select_item.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        holder.add.visibility = View.GONE

    }

    holder.btn_add_item.setOnClickListener {

        num += 1

        holder.amount.text = num.toString()

    }


}
```

}

```
enter code here
```

i want when i click on button relevant to a product just increase the item of that prodcut ...
also this image is clear shows my issue
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZtM5.png

Answer (score 0):

Because you use a global variable for all items (num variable). you should add new field to ModelProductMain model and increase or decrease it when the user clicks on button of that item.

Comment: your welcome, please mark it as answer if it helps you